# Load a Page without waiting for Page Load in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I would like to go to a login page , and only wait for the existance of the login credentials. I have tried:

```
page.goto('https://example.com/login')
```

And also tried all of the 4 options for waitUntil.

The issue is that the page is waiting for other things on the page to load that are not actually necessary for the login so it frequently times out.

I would like to go to the page an only wait for the login / password fields to be available - which I check anyway before filling the field.

thanks.

Comment: The code will depend on the page you want to automate

Comment: You can block loading unnecessary assets with https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-event-request

Comment: thanks @domlas  can you give an example?  if it works I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The fastest is if you don't specify `waitUntil`:

```js
await page.goto('https://example.com/login')
```

However, if you try not to wait it will throw an error when you try to interact with the page:

```js
// Notice no await here, meaning do not wait at all
page.goto('https://example.com/login')

// This will throw an error
await page.click('button')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wait for selector using this method

```
page.waitForSelector('#selectorID ').then(()=>{
//do smthg})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```